# How to map classes and properties from .NET application with .rdf ontology for rule checking with SWRL

Tags: c#, .net, owl, swrl, dotnetrdf

I am creating a plug-in within a .NET application to implement a rule-checking model based on the rules I created with SWRL from Protege, which would eventually return results/feedback after running the rule-checking within that application.

So far, I have imported my .rdf file into my plug-in with the dotNetRdf, and my next step would be mapping the classes and properties from the .NET application with the ontology, then running the pellet reasoner within the plug-in.

I am pretty new to the semantic web, and it would be such a tremendous help if I could get some insights on how data mapping between .NET framework and semantic web works with C#, and also if the pellet reasoner also works within the .NET

Thank you in advance!